# How do I target the second item in an array with Twig?

Tags: templating, array, index, position

I would like to select the second position in the array below. The problem is that this number is automatically changed. So I try to do this with .index function from Twig but I can not figure it out. Can someone help me?

array (
  7296680 => 
  array (
    ...
  ),
  7296635 => 
  array (
     ...
    'url' => 'vesten',
    'title' => 'Vesten',
  ),
)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [slice](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/slice.html) filter but it will return an array, so you either have to loop the result or access the first index

```
{% for item in array|slice(1, 1) %}
    {{ dump(item) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you can do `{{ myarray[1] }}` or even `{{ myarray.1 }}`

A more convoluted way would be to loop through the items and on the second pass, get the value.

```
{% set secondValue = null %}
{% for value in myArray %}
    {% if loop.index == 1 %}
        {% set secondValue = value %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```